# Splitting rows that contain a list of postcode prefixes into multiple rows, based on postcode area

Tags: excel, vba, t-sql

I have a table with several columns of data, one of which contains a list of different combined postcode prefixes on the same row.

Here's an example of the table layout:

```
+------+-----------------------------+
| Col1 |            Col2             |
+------+-----------------------------+
| a    | AB10; AB11;  DD10; DD9      |
| b    | S5; SS7; AA1; AA4           |
| c    | AB33; AB34; AB36; GG10; GS9 |
+------+-----------------------------+
```

I'm looking to split the postcode prefixes into multiple rows, based on the area of the postcode, as below:

```
+------+------------------+
| Col1 |       Col2       |
+------+------------------+
| a    | AB10; AB11       |
| a    | DD10; DD9        |
| b    | S5               |
| b    | SS7              |
| b    | AA1; AA4         |
| c    | AB33; AB34; AB36 |
| c    | GG10             |
| c    | GS9              |
+------+------------------+
```

I've found a VBA solution that splits, using the semicolon as a delimiter, but not how I need it done.

```vb
Sub splitByColB()
    Dim r As Range, i As Long, ar
    Set r = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B4").End(xlUp)
    Do While r.Row > 1
        ar = Split(r.Value, ";")
        If UBound(ar) >= 0 Then r.Value = ar(0)
        For i = UBound(ar) To 1 Step -1
            r.EntireRow.Copy
            r.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
            r.Offset(1).Value = ar(i)
        Next
        Set r = r.Offset(-1)
    Loop
End Sub
```

I could import the table in SQLExpress, so an SQL solution would also be welcome.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2014, Version 12.3.6024.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL solution I put together uses a T-SQL function called [DelimitedSplit8K](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%E2%80%9Ccsv-splitter%E2%80%9D-function) which works like the VB `SPLIT` function you are using.

```
-- Sample Data
DECLARE @table TABLE (Col1 CHAR(1) UNIQUE, Col2 CHAR(200));
INSERT @table (Col1,Col2) VALUES ('a','AB10; AB11;  DD10; DD9'),
  ('b','S5; SS7; AA1; AA4'),('c','AB33; AB34; AB36; GG10; GS9');

WITH xx(Col1,i,Pre) AS
(
  SELECT      t2.Col1, ss.Item+'', f.Pre
  FROM        @table AS t2
  CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(t2.Col2,';')                          AS s
  CROSS APPLY (VALUES(RTRIM(LTRIM(s.item))))                             AS ss(Item)
  CROSS APPLY (VALUES(SUBSTRING(ss.Item,0,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',ss.Item)))) AS f(Pre)
)
SELECT   xx.col1, col2 = STUFF((SELECT '; '+i 
                                FROM    xx AS x2 
                                WHERE   x2.Col1 = xx.Col1 AND x2.Pre = xx.Pre
                                FOR XML PATH('')),1,2,'')
FROM     xx
GROUP BY col1, xx.Pre;
```

Returns:

```
col1 Col2
---- ----------------------
a    AB10; AB11
a    DD10; DD9
b    AA1; AA4
b    S5
b    SS7
c    AB33; AB34; AB36
c    GG10
c    GS9
```

I also put together a solution that works with SQL Server 2017 which is cleaner (in case you upgrade or others or using 2017.)

```
-- Sample Data
DECLARE @table TABLE (Col1 CHAR(1) UNIQUE, Col2 CHAR(200));
INSERT @table (Col1,Col2) VALUES ('a','AB10; AB11;  DD10; DD9'),
  ('b','S5; SS7; AA1; AA4'),('c','AB33; AB34; AB36; GG10; GS9');

SELECT t.Col1, split.item
FROM @table AS t
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT      STRING_AGG(ss.Item,'; ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ss.Item)
  FROM        @table AS t2
  CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(t2.Col2,';') AS s
  CROSS APPLY (VALUES(TRIM(s.[value]))) AS ss(Item)
  WHERE       t.Col1 = t2.col1
  GROUP BY    SUBSTRING(ss.Item,0,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',ss.Item))
) AS split(item);
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use nested `dictionary` objects:

```
Sub splitByColB()
    Dim r As Range, ar, val1, val2, prefix As String
    Dim obj1 As Object, obj2 As Object

    Set obj1 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")

        For Each r In .Range("B2:B4")
            Set obj2 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
            With obj2
                For Each val2 In Split(Replace(r.Value2, " ", vbNullString), ";")
                    prefix = GetLetters(CStr(val2))
                    .Item(prefix) = .Item(prefix) & val2 & " "
                Next
            End With
            Set obj1.Item(r.Offset(, -1).Value2) = obj2
        Next

        .Range("A2:B4").ClearContents
        For Each val1 In obj1.keys
            .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(obj1(val1).Count).Value = val1
            For Each val2 In obj1(val1).keys
                .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = obj1(val1)(val2)
            Next
        Next
    End With
End Sub

Function GetLetters(s As String) As String
    Dim i As Long
    Do While Not IsNumeric(Mid(s, i + 1, 1))
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    GetLetters = Left(s, i)
End Function
```